# How, when and where does Grunt create a static directory?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

In the [Sample Angular-App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), the instructions say to "build" the project by commanding

```
grunt build
```

in the client directory.

Magically, when I run the app, the line that in the source appears like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
```

somehow turns into

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular-app.js"></script>
```

When, How and Where does this happen? For example, I can't find that `static` directory was created anywhere. Also, does this happen when I request the webpage or is it built before that? Can someone help me understand what's happening here?

Comment: It mounts `../client/dist` as `/static`. Look [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/config.js#L15-16) and [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/lib/routes/static.js#L9).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny so that happens on the server? But in the instructions, `grunt build` is called in the client, not the server

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny on top of that, there is no folder `client/dist`

Comment: `client/dist` is a [distdir](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/gruntFile.js#L32) for the client. `grunt` puts your Angular project there after building it.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny and where is that folder? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: `grunt build` should've created it. Have you built your client with `grunt build` command?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Yes I did. I don't see it :-)

Comment: Have you any warning or error when you run it?